# why is rspec telling me that this user is valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec

I have the following classes in Rails and am writing some rspec tests (any critiques are more than welcome as I'm a nOOb at rspec).

class User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

validates :email, :presence   => true ,
                  :format     => { :with => email_regex },
                  :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => true },
                  :on => :create
end
```

and in factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "my-name#{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "blue#{n}@12blue.com" }
  end
end
```

and in my rspec (users_spec.rb):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }
  it { user.should be_valid }
  it { user.should be_a(User) }
  it { user.should respond_to(:email) }

  it { user.email = " " }
  it { user.should_not be_valid } # this is causing the error 
end
```

and get

```
1) User 
     Failure/Error: it { user.should_not be_valid }
       expected valid? to return false, got true
```

But based upon the validates, user should be not be valid. What is going on here? What am I not getting (and I know it's my fault)?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the test failure surprises you because you think the user email should be `" "`.

In rspec every example is independent. This means that anything you did in a previous example is forgotten.

In your case your second to last example runs, builds a new, valid activerecord user whose email is `"blue4@12blue.com"`, overwrites that email with `" "` and then passes since it makes no assertions.

Then your last example runs, builds a new, valid activerecord user who's email is `"blue5@12blue.com"` and fails because the user is valid, it's email has not been overwritten.

You probably want something like this:

```
it 'should validate the email' do
  user.email = " "
  user.should_not be_valid
end
```

Comment: thx, makes more sense. Could I wrap them with a structure like a 'describe' to put those two together?

Comment: Not with a describe, no.  describe and context are meant to wrap groups of examples (https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/example-groups/basic-structure-describe-it). Instead remember that you can put more than one line of code in an example block.  I've added an example to my answer that should do what you want.  Hope that helps.

Comment: thx, makes more sense now - will probably have a bunch of other questions as some of this is a little abstract.

Comment: Feel free to ask them.  I'll check back in a few to answer.

Comment: dumb ? but is there a way to output the email value in that case like `puts user.email`?

Comment: Yes, you can customize the error messages for most rspec expectations.  For example, `user.should_not be_valid, "User was unexpectedly valid, #{user.attributes.inspect}"`.  https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/customized-message